# cURL for SFTP with private key authentication

Tags: curl, sftp

I need to upload files by SFTP from a PHP script. I think cURL is probably the way, as I have this available on the server.

Has anyone got an example of how to use cURL for SFTP using identity key authentication?

-- EDIT --

I've just noticed that HTTP PUT might be an alternative, but how secure it that?

Answer (score 13):

```
curl -u <username>: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub sftp://<remote_host>/<remote_path>
```

HTTP is unsecured, so any data you send during PUT (e.g. a password or the files you are uploading) could be snooped and read in plain text.  Depending on your application, this may or may not be a concern for you.

Comment: Why does curl need both the key and the public key?

Comment: @Angelo: *As of 7.39.0, curl attempts to automatically extract the public key from the private key file, so passing this option is generally not required.*  Source: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: I guess I mean:  why does curl require it and ssh does not?  Is ssh less secure to man-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: @Angelo The public key can be computed from the private key.  There is no security issue (per se) with either ssh or curl.  Prior to 7.39.0, curl was not computing the public key and it had to be provided manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the key if it's the default key as in your example. a bare `curl -u <username>: sftp://<remote_host>/<remote_path>` should suffice.

Comment: You're uploading via sftp, so your remark regarding unsecured HTTP does not make sense

Comment: @sstn, if you read the question, the security of HTTP was asked about.

Comment: I think that kbolino is incorrect. In RSA asymmetric encryption, neither the public nor the private key can be calculated from the other. Am I wrong?

Comment: Andy, if `curl -u <username>: sftp://<remote_host>/<remote_path>` uploads a file securely, I'm astounded. It doesn't specify the local file path or the public and private keys or the private key passphrase.

Comment: @DavidSpector but is it less astounding if you know that this behavior works in a documented fashion?  https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/scpsftp#authentication says, "curl will attempt to use your public key as found in the .ssh subdirectory in your home directory", so it looks like the reason this doesn't need to be specified each time is because there is a documented default.

Comment: Aha. Interesting. But still, SFTP requires the private key for the remote server. CURL probably prompts the user for it in this case. The fact is, the current documentation of SFTP is inadequate, so that it is impossible for a skilled programmer to implement it in PHP (either way) without the kind of help I have received.